# trying to pass "id" onclick of a button in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to pass an Id of the html element on onclick={clickEvent(this.Id)} in the .js of Lightning web component. Getting the following error: "Template expression doesn't allow CallExpression".

My use case is that: I have 3 buttons on parent component and have correspondingly child 3 components, and wish to render a respective child component in parent component on click of button.

So, though of passing the ID as parameter in switch-case in .js and display the respective component.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please make sure to include the relevant portions of your code, along with the specific issue you are struggling with and the complete text and location of any errors, in the body of your question. See [ask] for more about our expectations, and please [edit] your question to add information rather than posting comments.

Answer (score 6):

You can't pass parameters into expressions in LWC. You can, however, access attributes of the component via event.target:

```
onclick={clickEvent}
```

Then:

```
clickEvent(event) {
    let id = event.target.id;
    // ... //
```

Using the `id` is probably a poor choice, though, as it will be calculated by the runtime. Instead, you can use the `name` attribute to get a value that won't be modified by the runtime.

See this [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/qfW-EOCt/1/edit) I created for you.

Comment: This is generally a good answer, but you may want to note the following thread re: the `name` attribute (i.e. you evidently can't query for it): https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264202/how-to-target-lwc-by-name-attribute

Comment: @MatthewSouther I don't think it matters in this case, but that is a good thing to know regarding selecting elements by name.