# How to get the selected value of a picklist field in lightning combo box using template.getQuerySelector?

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, dom

How to get the selected value of a picklist field in lightning combo box using template.getQuerySelector?.

```
<lightning-combobox label={firstControllingFieldLabel}
                            name="Controlling Picklist Type"                                 
                            options={optionValuesFirstSet.controlling}
                            onchange={handleControllingFirstChange}
                            placeholder="None" 
                            value={selectedValuesFirstSet.controlling}
                            >
        </lightning-combobox>
```

For the above code i want to get the value i am selecting from UI using template.getQueryLocator?

i tried using below snippet:

```
 let typeOfCase = this.template.querySelector("[name='Controlling Picklist Type']");
        console.log('test type of case',typeOfCase);
```

But does not work. Any help please?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what is not working for you? Is the example given in docs, not enough? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/example

Comment: Hi @MohithShrivastava i was not able to find the attribute data-id in the documentation for lightning combo box , hence could not able to extract the selected value from the combo box using name attribute. But sophia's comment helped me to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `data-id` attribute instead of the `name` attribute. You can find an explanation for why name doesn't work [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264202/how-to-target-lwc-by-name-attribute). Also, when you use query selector, you will be returned the whole element. In order to get the value in the combobox, you need to use `.value`. Checking to make sure an element is returned before calling `.value` will prevent an error from being thrown.

```
<lightning-combobox label={firstControllingFieldLabel}
                            data-id="Controlling Picklist Type"                                 
                            options={optionValuesFirstSet.controlling}
                            onchange={handleControllingFirstChange}
                            placeholder="None" 
                            value={selectedValuesFirstSet.controlling}
                            >
        </lightning-combobox>
```

```
let combobox = this.template.querySelector("[data-id='Controlling Picklist Type']");
let typeOfCase = combobox ? combobox.value : null;
console.log('test type of case', typeOfCase);
```

It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish using query selector. Is it possible that you can just use the value variable? The variable can be set in your onchange event handler. See [this example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/example) in the combobox documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Sophia Gigliotti . It helped. I was able to achieve it. When i was searching for the attributes for lightning combo box i was not able to find a attribute named 'data-id'. Hence i was using name attribute. After using Data-id attribute i was able to extract the value selected from the combo box.