# Accesible Label and Input in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

When using standard HTML label and input tags the label and for"username" is not working as expected. From what I can see the ID for the input is being changed when the component renders to e.g. username-10. How can I prevent this from happening? The the form needs to meet accessibility requirements.

```
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
```

Comment: I feel that this [previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264202/how-to-target-lwc-by-name-attribute) is the best answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to be able to create labels was to use lightning "input" (and related) web components with the "label" attribute.

Code excerpts as examples:

```
<lightning-textarea name="caseNotes" label="Quick Notes" value={quickNotes}
    onkeyup={handleQuickNotesKeyUp} class="large-textarea"
    field-level-help="Use this field to record temporary notes about the Case.">
</lightning-textarea>

<lightning-input label="Phone" title="Phone" name="Phone"
    disabled={isNewContactProposed} value={newContact.Phone} variant=""
    type="phone" onkeyup={handleContactKeyUp} onblur={handleContactBlur}
    onfocus={handleContactFocus} class="newContactPhone">
</lightning-input>


<lightning-combobox name="caseRecordType" label="Record Type" onchange={handleChangeRecType}
    options={optCaseTypes} value={selRecordType} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small">
</lightning-combobox>
```

Note, I used custom "class" values along with jQuery and/or CSS to format the labels into the structure I wanted.  There was no other way to grab the "id" of the input fields as LWC appears to create the ids upon generation of the page.